# Generic function

Tags: c++, templates

I want to optimize the source code by writting a generic code for the repeated function. I am trying to implement the same using template function.

However i am not able to resolve the following error.
Any help for the same is due appreciated.

```
namespace elements_z0
{

Celements_z0::init() {...}
Celements_z0::run() {...runUser();...}
Celements_z0::runUser()
{.... 
//generic func
alice::CAliceOutput* alice_p;
runUser_r(alice_p, m_aliceSenderpin, m_alicecallback_p, m_aliceSenderpin_aui8, t_alice_enum);
....}

template<typename Interface> void runUser_r(Interface* interface_p, uint8_t* pin, interfacetype_p<Interface> interfacetyp_p, uint32_t Ifid_u32)
{
.......}
```

#### Error

1. Error:  #504-D: nonstandard form for taking the address of a member function
2. Error:  #849: expression must have arithmetic, enum, or pointer type

   runUser_r(alice_p, m_aliceSenderpin, m_alicecallback_p, m_aliceSenderpin_aui8, t_alice_enum);

### Edited 1:

Sorry about the typo error

Comment: What issues? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
template<typename Interface>
```

rather than

```
template(typename Interface)
```